# Predicate Logic - Software Testing

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

This is a section from Logic Coverage in Software Testing, I don't understand how the logic of the image below is resolved.

Assuming that the value of ***b*** is ***true***, ***(true <-> b)*** should resolve to ***true*** but the book says it resolves to ***b***. How is this possible?

The same goes for the opposite side, ***(false <-> b)*** should result to ***false***.

The point of this is to see how ***a*** determines the value of the predicate ***p***.

The book then says the following: *"That is, for any value of **b**, **a** determines the value of **p** without regard to the value for **b**"*

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Book - [link](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hiep/KiemthuPhanmem/Tailieuthamkhao/Introduction%20to%20Software%20Testing.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

He has replaced into the "logical function"

> $p := a \leftrightarrow b$

first $TRUE$ in place of $a$, getting $p_{a=TRUE} := TRUE \leftrightarrow b$ and then $FALSE$ in place of $a$, getting $p_{a=FALSE} := FALSE \leftrightarrow b$.

Then he uses the fact that $TRUE \leftrightarrow b$ is equivalent to $b$: check with truth table, and that $FALSE \leftrightarrow b$ is equivalent to $\lnot b$.

Thus:

> $p_a := p_{a=TRUE} ⊕ p_{a=FALSE} = b ⊕ \lnot b = TRUE$.

Comment: I get that part but shouldn't FALSE <-> b equal to FALSE (instead of not-b)?

Comment: @Adegoke A - $FALSE \leftrightarrow b$ is $FALSE \leftrightarrow TRUE= FALSE$ when $b$ is $TRUE$ and is $FALSE \leftrightarrow FALSE= TRUE$ when $b$ is $FALSE$. Thus, it is $\lnot b$. If you are not convinced, write the truth table.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not getting this. `FALSE↔TRUE=FALSE when b is TRUE`, why do we replace `FALSE` with `¬b`?

Comment: @AdegokeA - write a truth table: two lines... it is not so hard. $FALSE ↔ TRUE=FALSE$ when $b$ is TRUE, i.e. when $\lnot b$ is FALSE.